# Java List: When I call Arrays.fill() to fill an array, why it will appear some unexpected elements?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a beginner programmer, and it's my first time to ask a question here, if there is any worry about the format, I will feel really sorry. And at first, thank you for your answer, for your patience, and your pardon.

Actually the question is "loop until you find 4 different color Poker Cards". And I use an array to represent the Cards No, and an array to represent their Color.
and I fill the cardNo array by a for statement, the value is from 1 to 4, but it appears 0, I don't know why, and I think that is where the problem happened, and this is all my code.

```
public static void collect() {
    int num=0;
    //represent 52 Poker Cards
    int [] cardNo=new int[52];
    List list=new ArrayList<>();
    // `int[] color=new int[4]` to represent 4 colors, so the value 
    // of cardNo[] elements is the Color.
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        Arrays.fill(cardNo, i*13, (i+1)*13-1, i+1);
    }
    for(int n:cardNo) {
        list.add(n);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    // I use this for statement to check if it's worry with Arrays.fill(),
    // or it's about the list.add().
    for(int i:cardNo) {
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
    System.out.println(list);

    /*int[] color=new int[4];
    while(color[0]==0||color[1]==0||color[2]==0||color[3]==0) {
        int n=(int)(Math.random()*53);
        color[(int) list.get(n)-1]++;
        num++;
    }
    System.out.println("Number of picks: "+num);*/
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `toIndex` parameter of `Arrays.fill` is exclusive, so change:

```
Arrays.fill(cardNo, i*13, (i+1)*13 - 1, i+1);
```

to

```
Arrays.fill(cardNo, i*13, (i+1)*13, i+1);
```

The Javadoc:

> **void java.util.Arrays.fill(int[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, int val)**
>
> Assigns the specified int value to each element of the specified range of the specified array of ints. The range to be filled extends from index fromIndex, inclusive, **to index toIndex, exclusive**. (If fromIndex==toIndex, therange to be filled is empty.)

Comment: Oh my god, thank you very much, the problem has been solved. I really need to read the function description carefully! Nice first experience, thank you again!

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the tick symbol